# How do I call a JavaScript function from my code behind, the function being on a separate .js file?

Tags: c#, javascript

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "MyKey", "CreateNotificationTree(" + UserId + ")", true);
}
```

.js file:

```
function CreateNotificationTree(UserId)
{
    var data = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "../api/notifications/byuserid/" + UserId,
                contentType: "application/json"
            }
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                children: "notifications"
            }
        }
    });

    $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
        dataSource: data,
        loadOnDemand: true,
        checkboxes: {
            checkChildren: true
        },
        dataTextField: ["notificationType", "NotificationDesc"]
    });
}
```

Markup (do I need this?):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(CreateNotificationTree(UserId));
</script>
```

This is not working. The treeview does not get loaded on the page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=call+javascript+code+behind

Comment: The duplicate mentioned here doesnt help me 1 bit.

Comment: Try removing your function call from aspx page.Because from your code-behind you are already calling the function on page_load event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `script` block you are not assigning `CreateNotificationTree` to be called on `$(document).ready`, but call it right there. The correct way is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
      CreateNotificationTree(<%= this.UserId.ToString() %>);
   });
</script>
```

Then you don't need `RegisterClientScriptBlock` in `Page_Load`.

The second option is not to use `$(document).ready`, but call `RegisterStartupScript` (which writes script at the bottom of the page, when all DOM elements are available) instead of `RegisterClientScriptBlock` in `Page_Load`.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript
```